# onSensorChanged Google Map Rotate

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, android-sensors, compass

there is something bug to `onSensorChange` , I was able to move my map from facing north, my code was correct but its always rotate even the phone not moving

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor == mAccelerometer) {
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mLastAccelerometer, 0, event.values.length);
            mLastAccelerometerSet = true;
        } else if (event.sensor == mMagnetometer) {
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mLastMagnetometer, 0, event.values.length);
            mLastMagnetometerSet = true;
        }
        if (mLastAccelerometerSet && mLastMagnetometerSet) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mR, null, mLastAccelerometer, mLastMagnetometer);
                SensorManager.getOrientation(mR, mOrientation);
                float azimuthInRadians = mOrientation[0];
                float azimuthInDegress = (float)(Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadians)+360)%360;
                RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
                mCurrentDegree,
                -azimuthInDegress,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f);

                updateCamera(azimuthInDegress);
                }
            }, 3000);

        }

    }


    private void updateCamera(final Float bearing) {

        CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition.builder().target(latLng).zoom(20).bearing(bearing).build();
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos));


    }
```

I already put delay 5 seconds time but its not working, Please help me thanks

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the sensor. sensors does not always give you accurate values. its result depends on many factors.

Comment: Use my library https://github.com/hoananguyen/dsensor just start with the flag TYPE_COMPASS or TYPE_COMPASS_FLAT_ONLY. You do not even have to worry about the type of device (phone or tablet). Your code would be wrong for tablet.

Comment: Hey i saw your github and i just wonder how to import this, its said that i'll put this to build.gradle compile project(':dsensor'); but still not working is there something that i missed? @HoanNguyen

Comment: can you give me your exisiting work project or example for this github sir ? -@HoanNguyen

Comment: In Android Studio File --> New --> Import Module and import the directory where you download the library

Comment: Hi @JudeBautista, could you find the solution for avoiding flickering ?

Comment: @AknKplnoglu Hi sir I already found out the solution thanks,

Comment: @JudeBautista can you share your solution? Because i could not handle still.