# Is there a way to animate Xamarin.Forms.Maps pin movement

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, maps

I just wanted to know if there was a way in xamarin to translate changing a map pins positions and possibly rotating a custom map pin to match the direction of movement. I'd like to avoid custom renderers **IF** possible but I'm open to the idea.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

@Andy Sinclair's answer is a good starting point (as are [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom)), but if you want to animate a map pin (with lat, long, and possibly bearing), you'll need to animate each scalar value separately, like so:

```
var position = yourTargetPinPosition;
new Animation {
    // Animate the change in latitude
    { 0, 1, new Animation(lat => pin.Position = new Position(lat, pin.Position.Longitude), pin.Position.Latitude, position.Latitude) },
    // Animate the change in longitude
    { 0, 1, new Animation(lng => pin.Position = new Position(pin.Position.Latitude, lng), pin.Position.Longitude, position.Longitude) }
// Play the animation over 2000ms with a new frame every 16ms
}.Commit(map, "PinAnimation", 16, 2000, Easing.SinInOut, (v, c) => {
    // If the animation is cancelled for any reason, update the pin position to the target value
    if (c) {
        pin.Position = position;
    }

    // Optionally, pan the map to the new position after the animation is complete
    var mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01);
    map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
}, () => false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps).

#### About Postion

You can clear first and add them again on the map to refresh the position

Refer to [here](http://%20https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118999/refresh-pins-positions-in-google-maps).

#### About Direction

You can use **BEARING**  to achieve the effect.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450969/rotate-google-map-to-display-my-real-time-direction).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer
How different is xamarin forms maps vs xamarin forms google maps? I've got some progress with polyline and wanted to know how much work I need to repeat

Comment: I started reading about it and it doesn't seem to be too much work to redo my project with this control, guessing I might need to change my custom map.

Comment: @Kaizer69 Hi , what's problem did you meet with ?

Comment: Hi Cole,
I initially marked this as an answer since it using googlemaps package instead of maps fixed a whole lot of issues but I could not see anything in their documentation about translating, animating movement from one position to another, map pins which was the first part of my question. I was already able to change positions but the pins just magically move instead of smoothly transitioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom animation to animate the movement of a pin on a Xamrin Forms Map like this:

```
    var animation = new Animation(a => pin.Position = new Position(pin.Position.Latitude + 0.0001, pin.Position.Longitude), 1, 2);
    animation.Commit(this, "PinAnimation", 100, 10000, Easing.SinInOut , null, () => false);
```

More details on Xamarin Custom Animations on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom)

Hope this helps.